# Sticky Header for Desktop Width Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I'm not sure if it's called sticky header but This may be a easy question for you guys!  I do have a sticky header.. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw2G/) here

JS CODE:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("#header").css({position: 'fixed'});
}
else {
    $("#header").css({position: 'inherit'});
}
})
});
```

CSS:

```
#header { background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 20px; margin: 0; }
#test { height: 2000px; }
```

Main Question: I want this script to run on screen 780 above only. I don't want it in my tablet and mobile versions.. Help

Optional: Can you suggest/improvised my code by doing a jsfiddle? Something like adding a cool effect, transitions etc..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT **
I'm not sure if this be will a different question..

I have updated my codes and replaced this

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
```

into

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $(this).width() > 780) {
```

In a way,it works.. but it doesnt return the properties of the css for smaller versions.. 
To explain it well, here's the [UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw2G/2/) jsfiddle.

1. For 780 Above when you scroll down the header becomes RED and when you scroll up it becomes black again ( just like i wanted)
2. If you re-size your window below 780 the header should be gray. and if scrolled down and up again.( position should be inherit not fixed). **color still it should be grey**

im my jsfiddle case, it becomes black..

Comment: Have a look at $(window).width(); and incorporate this into your code.

Give it a shot and if you are still stuck, come back with your code :)

Comment: Hi all, please the question again.. i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a CSS class, and use a media query on that class to determine whether or not it should be fixed. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw2G/3/).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $("#header").addClass("stickyHeader");
        }
        else {
            $("#header").removeClass("stickyHeader");
        }
    })
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 780px) {
    .stickyHeader { position: fixed; }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is another way to do it :)  but it created addtional problems.. please see my question again.

Comment: What additional problems? You can just add your rules to the stickyHeader class. See http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw2G/4/

Comment: Well it doesn't work because the fiddle box is less than 780px so the header isn't fixed. To test it as a sticky switch the media query to like 280px.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the height of the window with jquery

```
if($(window).width() >= 780){
  alert("bigger")
}
```

Comment: Firstly you need to execute that method, ie its;

    $(window).height()

And secondly wouldn't he want width instead?

Comment: if ($(this).scrollTop() > 187 && $(this).width() > 780) {  } i Added this,, it worked but it doesnt return the elements into it's original state when scrolled back.. that is for 320, 480 and 780 viewport

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries doesn't help you?, you can do something like:

```
#header { 
    position: fixed;
    background: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 20px; 
    margin: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s;
}

#test { 
    height: 2000px; 
}

@media all and (max-width: 780px){
    #header {
        position:inherit;
    }
}
```

you can see it on you gist [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw2G/1/)